# link to pcap with pf_ring

Tags: static-libraries, dynamic-linking, libpcap, ldd

I'm trying to use libpcap that was compiled with pf_ring.
I got the sources from ntop, and compiled it.

However, there's something I don't understand (sorry for the newbie linking question):
I wanted to know if my application used the correct pcap version (the one with pfring),
so I typed ldd  and didn't see pcap at all, only pfring.

I looked at the output and saw only pfring.so and not pcap, although I dynamically linked to both libs.

I looked at the Makefile of libpcap and saw it linked statically with pfring.a.
I thought I don't have to link with pfring at all, because it's a part of pcap, but got undefined reference.

Does anyone know why I get the undefined reference error and why don't I see libpcap in the ldd output when I link to it dynamically?

Thanks,
Ron

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure you did all of the following steps:

```
//Installation
sudo su
cd kernel; make install
cd ../userland/lib; make install
insmod ./kernel/pf_ring.ko
```

then remove the current libpcap and all of its dependencies from your system.

the pfring enabled libpcap is under /userland/libpcapx as you know.

if you are using pf_ring enabled libpcap in your application simply link libpcap.a to your program.